# How to print JSON stringified string with \r\n?

Tags: javascript, json

I get this object: `{a:"a\r\na", b:"b\r\nb"}`. I used `JSON.stringify()` to create a string from the object, however the output I got is:

```
"{

  "a": "a\r\na",

  "b": "b\r\nb"

}"
```

What I actually want is:

```
"{

  "a": "a


a",

  "b": "b

b"

}"
```

How should I get this?

Comment: This isn’t possible. It wouldn’t be valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mozilla docs (see "[Issue with plain JSON.stringify for use as JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)") seem to address this directly:

```
function jsFriendlyJSONStringify (s) {
return JSON.stringify(s).
    replace(/\u2028/g, '\\u2028').
    replace(/\u2029/g, '\\u2029');
}
```

**Update:**

With the help of OP and contributors below,

```
function jsFriendlyJSONStringify (s) {
return JSON.stringify(s).
    replace(/\\r/g, '\r').
    replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
}
```

provides a more general solution.

Comment: This doesn’t really address `\r\n`, though.

Comment: @Xufox, u2028 and u2029 *are* \r and \n.  (At least in my in my console).  Maybe rethink the down-vote, or explain further?

Comment: Need to use replace('\\r', '\r').replace('\\n', '\n') instead, this works. Somehow /\u2028/ and \\u2028 does not work though

Comment: That is indeed viable workaround for the presentation issue, but it uses different characters then requested. `\r` and `\n` are u000d and u000a respectively. The same presentation in the console doesn't imply being the same character. You should point that out in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually dependent on the browser, editor or text field where you’re displaying these values. If you display it on a website, you can replace the CR/LF by `<br>`.

Also, Windows is using CR/LF in MS Office Excel files whereas MS Office Excel on Mac is just using `\n` (new line).

tl;dr: you can not change the display “style” without changing the actual content.